# How to separate procedures which insert, update and delete records in Oracle for a Particular Table

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, toad

I have an application in which there are many tables and many procs.

I want to get the procedure which only inserts.

For example in TOAD, when I search the table properties for the Table EMP, we can get the list of Procedures, functions and Triggers.

How can I get the Procedures which only Inserts into the table EMP.

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is, search for keywords `insert`, `update`, `delete` from `*_SOURCE` data dictionary view for that particular `procedure`.

The search column is `TEXT` in `*_SOURCE`. If you want to search in the same schema, look into `USER_SOURCE`.

Something like -

```
Select * from USER_SOURCE
where NAME = UPPER('my_procedure')
AND LOWER(text) like '%update%'
and LOWER(text) NOT like '%insert%'
and LOWER(text) NOT like '%delete%'
```

Above query's output would make sure the `PROCEDURE` is only UPDATING.

Why to search `FUNCTIONs`? Doing `DML` via `PROCEDURE` is fine, why would you do DML inside a `FUNCTION`? You shouldn't be looking for FUNCTIONs here.